# Is it possible rename string in file during 'Use this template' on github?

Tags: github, github-actions

I have a bash file in my template repo, it contains the url of current repo, what i want is when another user use this template, in their repo should be contain their new git url repo

i don't know where to start or what to search...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Doesn't seem to be possible as of now:

- There's nothing in the [offical docs](https://docs.github.com/en/github/creating-cloning-and-archiving-repositories/creating-a-template-repository).
- And searching for it turns up sources saying that it isn't possible at the moment:

> Now that github has template repositories, an obvious next step is to enable "variables" to make it easy to stamp out customized repositories based on a set of metadata passed in to the template.

Source: https://github.com/isaacs/github/issues/1716

> Hey! As far as what I have read, this is not possible. It would be awesome to see this get added. I think the best thing we can do at this point is to add a feature request.

Source: https://github.community/t/variable-substitution-for-github-template-repository-usage/2881

Comment: thanks for the github issues link, that answers me the possibility status as today

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for the late reply.. but yes.

[Here](https://github.com/rochacbruno/python-project-template/blob/main/.github/workflows/rename_project.yml#L9) is a cool trick using github actions which I just found.. It basically determines if it should do a rename only when a new repo is created.

There are a few bash scripts that run, one includes a little `sed` to rename contents of files. Pretty clever anyway

I also found an good article afterwards that actually explains the tricks used in the template by [Simon Willison](https://simonwillison.net/2021/Aug/28/dynamic-github-repository-templates/) (2021)